# How to apply SSRT to an existing image with associated depth map?

Tags: rendering, human-vision

I have the following image and depth map from a CV paper:

[image]

I want to know if there is an existing way to apply screen space rendering to a pre-existing image.

Before someone yells ate me saying "Why render over a literal picture when you can only make it worse!"

I have a program that changes multiple aspects of the original image, (color of certain objects and re-texturing of some surfaces).

So the original colors are wrong with respect to the modified image.

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I am not trying to implement it, I want to know if something that does something like that exists already.

Comment: It sounds like something a VFX compositor like Nuke would do, but I haven't tried it myself.